# Windows 10 UEFI won't boot (solved)

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive, boot

I can't boot my Windows 10 Pro mounted on GPT partition.

For a couple of days it entered a loop caused by WinRE. The strange thing is that no recovery function was able to get my drive to boot.
I opted to repair startup, then restore to a point in time, but neither of these tasks would run. For example, I would choose a specific restore point, and it would appear to start the restore process, but immediately return to the recovery menu.
In the log that it stores on the disk it said that the reason for the problem could not be identified.

I don't remember at this point what command I used, but I managed to get it out of that loop and there I could see that it was an error "0xc000014c" and that some file in the folder "C:\Windows\System32\Config\System" was missing. corrupt or did not exist.

I have manually recovered lost EFI and MSR partitions, but have never seen this error before, although it is more predictable than the others.

Thinking that there could be bad sectors, I checked the disk with HDD Regenerator and with Victoria, and it is in optimal conditions, so I discarded this option.

Then I have gone through dozens of pages and videos in which they explain how to solve the problem but focused on the partition problem. I have also consulted the Microsoft technical documentation, but I cannot find a specific solution for this case.

That is why I turn to you so that if anyone knows how to solve this problem, help me since I have many programs installed (on a 3TB disk), and reinstalling them would not be the best solution.

Comment: Your putting too much trust into a couple of tools that aren't even "mainstream" (I'm being nice here). It has all the hallmarks of a failing drive that's about to fail completely.

Comment: @ChanganAuto I understand, but I omitted to say that I used "chkdsk /F /R" first, which did not find any errors on the disk.

Comment: If you're confident then you can try reinstalling Windows. It has an option that preserves your personal data and user installed programs but you probably should try the one-size-fits-all approach at https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-10-boot-error-0xc000014c/877ac7df-76a9-4dc8-a99b-3b6992dce8f9 , except, of course, "fixmbr" because you have an UEFI mode installed and GPT, not MBR.

Comment: "I have manually recovered lost EFI and MSR partitions' - If you are restoring partitions, then you have bad sectors, which means there is a good chance enough of those bad sectors contained system files making the system unbootable.  Healthy working drives DO NOT require partitions to be restore unless they were accidently removed (which isn't the case here).

Comment: @Ramhound I wrote about recovering lost partitions because it has happened to me on other disks (not this one), and I have recovered them.
I've already checked the drive with "chkdsk /F /R" several times and it didn't find any problem, then I tried "HDD Regenerator" and "Victoria" which didn't find any bad sectors either. That's why I rule out a disk problem, I'm inclined to a startup file problem due to a power outage for example.

Comment: HDD Regenerator and Victoria are worthless applications, the only solution to a disk problem, is replacing under warranty or sending it off to data recovery to save as much as you can that eventually gets put on your replacement drive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the end I was able to recover the disk by my own means.
What I did was the following:
I did a clean install of Windows 10 in a virtual machine, then copied the missing/corrupted "System" file to the non-booting disk.
Obviously, since it was not the file corresponding to the previous installation, Windows took a long time to boot, but it ended up doing so.
I immediately ran the following commands:

```
DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /CheckHealth (no failure detected)
DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /ScanHealth (detected failures but they were reversible)
DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth /Source:wim:D:\sources\install.wim:1 /LimitAccess (I had to do it with a USB with the Windows image)
DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /StartComponentCleanup (delete all useless files in the WinSxS folder)
```

Subsequently, I ran the command:

```
SFC /Scannow (which fixed all inconsistencies)
```

And everything was perfect, even running much faster than before the failure.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't find what the problem is, especially after having
disk problems, I would suggest some tests and a complete re-installation.

Use a Linux Live USB to save your data (if no backup) and to check
the SMART attributes of the disk.

If no SMART errors are found, install Windows from scratch, while
formatting the disk using slow format (not quick), to better
reinitialize all the sectors.

After the format, the disk will become one Unallocated space.
Install Windows to this space (do not allocate the partitions yourself).

If errors still occur, check the hardware some more by running
[MemTest86](https://www.memtest86.com/)
overnight.
If nothing is found, perhaps it's time to consult a repair-shop.